# How to upload iOS build only for TestFlight internal testing using CLI altool?

Tags: testflight, xcode-tools

Xcode 15 has a new feature - upload iOS build without the possibility of publishing to AppStore:

[image]

But how can I use this feature in the command line app `altool`?
I can't find appropriate arguments for this, although Fastlane already has - at least it [was mentioned in the GitHub discussion](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/21525#discussioncomment-7329340):

```
gym(
    ...
    export_options: {
        testFlightInternalTestingOnly: true
    }
)
```